# Se borra la SESSION en PHP cuando hago clic en un botón o toco F5

Tags: php, css3, session, materialize

Formule mi pregunta en esta pagina pero en su versión oficial, pero me cuesta mucho expresarme correctamente en ingles.

**INTRODUCCIÓN** 
Tengo un sistema en PHP que tiene dos tipos de usuarios, Administrador y Usuario, tengo una carpeta "headers" y dos archivos "header-user.php" y "header-admin.php". Las paginas que puede usar el administrador tienen require_once('headers/header-admin.php'); y las del usuario require_once('headers/header-user.php');

**PROBLEMA** 
El problema es que mi sistema no se adaptaba a todas las pantallas y mucho menos a los móviles, por lo que decidí usar materializecss, por ende, yo reemplace los archivos "header-user.php" y "header-admin.php" por los que usan materialize y ahora se adaptan perfectamente, el problema es muy raro y lo voy a comentar a continuación:
Cuando hago uso de los nuevos headers y toco F5 o hago clic en cualquier opción de la barra de navegación, mi SESSION de PHP se elimina.

**TEST QUE HICE** 
Hice los siguientes testeos:
1- Reemplazar nuevamente los headers por los antiguos y la SESSION no se borra, funciona todo perfecto.
2- Hice un echo del nombre de la persona que inicia sesión y lo muestra después de iniciar sesión pero si toco F5 o alguna opción de la barra de navegacion ya no se muestra ese nombre (tuve que comentar los chequeos de seguridad para hacer este test porque sino el sistema me saca y me dice que debo iniciar sesión )

**CÓDIGO CLASE: LOGICA MÉTODO: login()**

```
//Consultas a base de datos y chequeos antes de aquí      
$_SESSION["Usuario"] = array(
                            "id"=>$datos[0],
                            "nombre"=>$datos[1],
                            "apellido"=>$datos[2],
                            "correo"=>$datos[3],
                            "movil"=>$datos[4],
                            "cargo"=>$datos[5],
                            "empresa"=>$datos[6],
                            "foto"=>$datos[7],
                          //  if($datos[7] == "") {"foto"=>"no-photo.png";}
                            "privilegio"=>$privilegio,
                            );

                            if($privilegio == "usuario"){echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="profile.php";</script>';}
                            if($privilegio == "administrador"){echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="profile-admin.php";</script>';}
```

**CÓDIGO que esta presente en todas las paginas exclusivas para admins**

```
   <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION["Usuario"]))
            {
                if($_SESSION["Usuario"]["privilegio"] == "usuario")
                {
                 //Usuario
                 echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="profile.php?error=E002";</script>';
                }

            }
            else{ //No inicio sesion
                 echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="login.php?error=E001";</script>';
            }  
        require_once("headers/header-admin.php");
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código en el cual creas la sesión?

Comment: @FrancisoRomero acabo de editar mi pregunta, en donde incluí lo que solicitas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Dónde asignas el valor a la variable `$privilegio`? ¿No tendría que ser `if($_SESSION["Usuario"]["privilegio"] == "usuario")`?

Comment: Lo que tu te refrieres es el chequeo. Todas las paginas tienen un chequeo, algunas son solo para users y otras solo para admins. Aquí te dejo el code que hago para una pag exclusiva para admins: <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION["Usuario"]))
  {
   if($_SESSION["Usuario"]["privilegio"] == "usuario")
   {
    //Usuario
    echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="profile.php?error=E002";</script>';
   }

  }
  else{ //No inicio sesion
       echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="login.php?error=E001";</script>';
  }  
 require_once("headers/header-admin.php");

Comment: @FranciscoRomero lo puse en la pregunta inicial para que sea mas legible. Las otras paginas hacen lo mismo, pero si son exclusivas para usuarios, en caso de detectar un administrador lo redirige a su perfil. También arriba hago session_start();

Comment: No relacionado directamente con tu pregunta, pero ¿por qué haces la redirección con JS en lugar de usar `header("Location")` en PHP?

Comment: no me funciona el header a veces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es:

```
$_SESSION["privilegio"] = $valor;
```

Yo lo usaba como array, asignándole un array.

Answer (score 0):

por favor revisa que la sesion este activa o de lo contrario activala usando `session_start();` despues de esto ya puedes usarla, de lo contrario no guardara nada ni llamara nada por que nunca guardaste algo en la sesion.

**edit 1** 
La sesión puede guardar arreglos, solo que no los acepta ingresando el array directo, para esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
$_SESSION['arreglo']['variable1'];
$_SESSION['arreglo']['variable2'];
$_SESSION['arreglo']['variable3'];
$_SESSION['arreglo']['variable4'];
```

espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: El error era porque guardaba en un array, ahora simplemente hago esto: $_SESSION["privilegio"] = $valor;

Comment: la sesion acepta arreglos, caso contrario de las cookies, revisa lo q acabe de poner en la respuesta @Strelok

Comment: si ya solucionaste el problema por favor contesta tu pregunta con la solucion y marcala como resuleta.

Comment: ya esta listo, gracias.